# Notable to load twritter jar file in spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am working on basic spark twitter application. But I am not able to load twitter jar file in spark cluster.

```
spark-shell --jars /usr/local/Twitter/spark-streaming-twitter_2.11-2.0.1.jar,\
    /usr/local/Twitter/twitter4j-core-4.0.6.jar,\
    /usr/local/Twitter/twitter4j-stream-4.0.6.jar
```

I am using above command to add the jar file in spark env. But I am getting file not found exception

> 18/03/28 09:11:39 ERROR SparkContext: Failed to add
>   file:/usr/local/Twitter/spark-streaming-twitter_2.11-2.0.1.jar to
>   Spark environment java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jar
>   /usr/local/Twitter/spark-streaming-twitter_2.11-2.0.1.jar not found

Comment: can you make sure that `spark-streaming-twitter_2.11-2.0.1.jar` is present on `/usr/local/Twitter/` directory

Comment: check jar files are avaiilable

Comment: Your error is still saying it could not found in that path

Comment: yes I know..I have placed jar file correctly.. I am running the script in ubuntu shell.. Do i need to run the same in spark shell?

Comment: can you share the screenshoot